# Jdbctemplate queryforObject .IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 10

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

This is my DAO code

```
@Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    }
    public JSONObject getdata(UserBean userBean)
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select username from customer", new RowMapper<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public JSONObject mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
            {
                jsonObject.put("username",rs.getString("username"));
                return jsonObject;
            }

        });

    }
```

Then this is my controller code

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value="/doLogin")
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute @Valid UserBean userBean,BindingResult result)
    {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
        if(!result.hasFieldErrors())
        {
            if(!combatService.authenticateUser(userBean)) 
            {
                result.addError(new ObjectError("err", "Invalid Credentials"));

            } 
            else
                {
                 if(retrieveService.getdata(userBean) != null)
                 {
                     JSONObject responseArray=new JSONObject();
                     responseArray.put("usernames",retrieveService.getdata(userBean));
                     return new ModelAndView("welcomes", responseArray);
                }   
                }
        }
        return view;
        }
```

And this is error

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 10

Comment: ...and [this is the place](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) you are supposed to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does a straight up `SELECT username FROM customer`, meaning, this query returns *ALL* usernames. Presumably, there are currently 10 records in your database.

You need to run `SELECT username FROM customer WHERE (something something)`.

You haven't pasted your `UserBean` code, but assuming it has a `getUserId()` method in it, you'd do something like: `return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select username from customer WHERE userId = ?", new RowMapper<JSONObject>() { ... }, userBean.getUserId())`. Note how there's a new parameter at the end, after your rowmapper, with the value for the question mark in your SQL query.

Comment: I retrieve all username